# ButterKnife выдает NullPointer. что делать?

Tags: android

Я скачал библиотеку `ButterKnife`, установил плагин, как на сайте плагина. В итоге получаю NullPointerExeption.

Есть ли в интернете какой-нибудь плагин, который по `R.layout.main` создаст в Java-классе все id элементов?

`Button`, `ListView` и т.д. , как плагин `ButterKnife`, только он не работает почему-то.

Выдает ошибку эту

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com../com...Activites.News1}: java.lang.NullPointerException

 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                            at com...Activites.News1$override.onCreate(News1.java:36)
                                                                            at com...Activites.News1$override.access$dispatch(News1.java)
                                                                            at com...Activites.News1.onCreate(News1.java:0)
```

Вот код самой прогармммы

```
   public class News1 extends AppCompatActivity{
    String textShare = "";
    boolean tabLikeBool = false;
    @BindView(R.id.tab_like)
    TextView tabLike;
    @BindView(R.id.tab_msg)
    TextView tabMsg;
    @BindView(R.id.tab_share)
    TextView tabShare;
//    TextView tabLike,tabMsg,tabShare;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.news1);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
//        tabLike= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tab_like); tabLike.setOnClickListener(this);
//        tabMsg= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tab_msg); tabMsg.setOnClickListener(this);
//        tabShare= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tab_share); tabShare.setOnClickListener(this);
        tabLike.setText("4");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
```

Вот градл `compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.1.0'`

Почему у всех работает. А у меня нет

Comment: Опишите детальнее вашу проблему, желательно прикрепить логи ошибок. P.S. Butterknife одина из лучших библиотек

Comment: @AdamLuisSean, Ну ошибка NullPointer. выдает

Comment: У всех все работает, а вы такой особенный что у вас что то не работает. Может это вы что то делаете не так? Покажите ваш код.

Comment: @temq. Я что с луны чтоли? Как у вас может работать. Щяс скину. Обычный nullPointer который не может найти View в Layout. Хотя он там есть

Comment: @pavlofff, Ну вы ведь сами сказали что вопрос не понятен. Я и переделал. А чо не так - то?

Comment: @pavlofff, да работает. А как подключить все это через Project Structure в Android studio.?

Comment: @pavlofff, я хочу просто чтобы не делать это при каждом создании какого то приложения.

Comment: Данная библиотека не подключается через UI-интерфейс Project Structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что у вас не полностью подключена библиотека так как для ее работы с некоторых пор не достаточно просто прописать *dependences* в build.gradle модуля проекта.
Для подключения библиотеки ButterKnife нужно проделать несколько действий, [согласно инструкции.](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife#download)

Добавить *classpatch* в build.gradle всего проекта (файл в корневой папке проекта):

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
   }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
  }
```

}

Подключить плагин и добавить следующие зависимости в build.gradle модуля (файл в папке исходников приложения):

```
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
  ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.1.0'
  apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.1.0'
}
```

В связи с этими манипуляциями библиотека подключается некорректно через GUI- интерфейс добавления зависимостей в окне Project Structure, правильно подключить ее можно только прописав нужные строки непосредственно в файлах проекта.